# System.Web.HttpContext.Current is static between requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, static-members

In my web application I'm using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` and it represents the current  hit context, I was wondering how its accessible from everywhere until i noticed that its a `static` member ! 
While its a static member how it keeps its value while if two requests received in almost the same time.
like the following :

```
#Req1----> | set the value of the static field to req1
#Req2----> | set the value of the static field to req2
#Req1      | use that static its supposed to be req2 while its req1
```

did I miss-understand something or there is a trick in it or what ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very intelligent question!

`HttpContext.Current` is implemented as a thread-local variable. Actually, it is implemented using `LogicalCallContext` but that behaves like a thread-local.

Think of it like this:

```
[ThreadLocal]
public static HttpContext Current;
```

And yes, this means that only the primary request thread can access it. It will be null on additional threads that you start.

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot for your answer! everything is much clearer now, but i have one question, what do you mean with `its implemented using LogicalCallContext`, and thanks again for your very helpful answer.

Comment: When you pry the property open with Reflector you find that the value does not come from a static thread-local field but from CallContext and in turn from LogicalCallContext. They are low-level infrastructure classes which I know little about. They are essentially per-thread data-structures (but not quite). I think each request in ASP.NET or WCF has one such call context but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: thanks a lot Sir, I'll search more about this subject, but your answer was complete! thanks again.